# Returning byte array from Azure Text-to-speech back-end to front-end gives DOMException: Unable to decode audio data error

Tags: javascript, .net, text-to-speech, web-audio-api, azure-cognitive-services

I am running the Azure Text-to-speech service through my .NET back-end. The general idea behind this is to stream `byte` data to the front-end application, which can then be decoded and played through the browser's audio context and corresponding API.

The REST endpoint runs the following code in order to generate the `byte[]` data:

```
public byte[] ConvertTextToSpeechStream(string text)
{
    SpeechConfig speechConfiguration = SpeechConfig.FromEndpoint(new System.Uri("https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken"), "<subscription-key>");

    using (SpeechSynthesizer speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfiguration, null))
    {
        SpeechSynthesisResult result = speechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text).Result;
        return result.AudioData;
    }
}
```

and returns back the `byte[]` data to the caller. This is per the Azure Text-to-speech documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=script%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-csharp#get-result-as-an-in-memory-stream).

The front-end which invokes this code is running the following JavaScript code within Vue.JS component:

```
audioPlayByteStream: function () {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    audioContext = new AudioContext();
    
    fetch('my-endpoint-url', {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ Text: "This is my test text!" }),
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      return response.arrayBuffer();
    })
    .then(function (buffer) {
      console.log(buffer);
      audioContext.decodeAudioData(buffer, function (decodedData) {
        source.buffer = decodedData;
        source.connect(audioContext.destination);
      });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Request failed", error);
    });
},
```

Consider that the `audioPlayByteStream` function is currently invoked on a button click event. It contains hard-coded text that I want to be played out through the browser. The code fails on the `decodeAudioData` method.

The following error comes up when running the code through Google Chrome (Version 92.0.4515.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)): `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data`. When running the same code in Mozilla Firefox (91.0.1 (64-bit)), I receive the following error message instead: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type.`. I've been trying to explicitly specify the `SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat` based on this [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechsynthesisoutputformat?view=azure-dotnet) with no luck; still got the `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type.` exception.

Anyone else that has faced this before and found a way to resolve it? I've seen various of threads on the same topic, but nothing really helped as I've tried utilizing different snippets from the community, but all resulted in the same error.

Appreciate the assistance on this.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this? Having a similar problem in Python

Comment: @Steven Matthews No, unfortunatelly. I couldn't succeed routing through the backend, so had to rely on the frontend only approach for the time being (which was not desired). I was hoping that someone will point out where the gap is, as I've struggled for a while and then simply gave up..

Comment: I ultimately saved as a file and then uploaded that saved file after loading it. A bit dirty, but it did the job.